# Difference bewteen declaring a NSString with alloc and init and assigning with @"myString"

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsstring

Currently I'm troubled with a small understanding issue on Objective-C. As example following Aaron Hillegass's book, I'm wondering about assigning an `NSString` in the `init` method of a class a value like in this example (For people who know the book, this is used in the `Person` class of RaiseMan):

```
- (id)init
{
   if(![super init])
     return nil;
   myString = @"New entry";
   return self;
}
```

This string isn't allocated by me, so normally I shouldn't bother about releasing it.

BUT! What happens in a setter-method of this string? Following the memory management rules the method should look like:

```
- (void)setMyString:(NSString *)newString
{
    if(myString != newString) {
        [myString release];
        [newString retain];
        myString = newString;
    }
}
```

Why does `[myString release]` work? I've read somewhere, that with `= @"bla"` assigned strings can't be released.

And is initializing with `= @"bla"` the right way? Or should I use `alloc` and `init` instead?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *constantString = @"constantString";
```

String like `constantString` are said to be from a private(?) class NSConstantString and they are alive through all your program life. Off-course release and  retain work, (in the mean that they won't give you a exception or crash) They just do nothing.

Read more [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSString)

Also you said in one of your comments that it would be a`{@property(..., copy) NSString myString;`But what you are showing us is a typical `@property(..., retain)`

Comment: Oops, sorry for the retain and copy mistake, it should be indeed retain in my comment! So that means, if I create several objects like in my given init Method, I will have a huge amount of undisposeable strings, right? (= memory leak?) EDIT: Ah found the answer of this in your link. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, string constants of the form @"..." are actually a child class of NSString that redefine retain and release as no-ops. This allows the compiler to store those string constants in the data segment of your executable instead of on the heap.

Comment: they do nothing (no operation)

Answer (score 0):

Is `myString` declared in the header-file? Like: `@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString myString`. If that is the case, then `myString` is retained. Otherwise, it's not necessary to release it.

Comment: Since he is defining his own setter  then @properties attributes, like retain,  are only advisory. (Obviously, he should do as the attributes suggest) However I don't think that is not an answer for the string initialization.

Comment: It is not defined as a property. But would @property(readwrite, copy) not also try to release the old value first?