# Variable released prematurely during asynchronous request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

My memory-management and threading knowledge is very limited, so I may be missing something really basic. I've found a work-around for this problem, but it really, really bothers me that I can't see what's happening.

I have a class that makes two asynchronous HTTP requests, one for an XML configuration file  and another for an image. Because there are two asynchronous requests going on in the same class, I'm reusing the same `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods (maybe factor). I first asynchronously fetch the configuration file and extract two urls, stored as `sponsorImage` and `sponsorUrl`. Then I use the value of `sponsorImage` to asynchronously fetch image data. I've found, though, that after I've got my image (after the second asynchronous event has completed), `sponsorUrl` has been released.

I accidentally found that I can prevent `sponsorUrl` from getting released if I "do something to it" in the method where the image request is created -- and by "do something", I mean just that. Basically, my code looks like this:

```
- (void) loadImage
{
    sponsorUrl = [sponsorUrl stringByAppendingString:@""];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sponsorImage];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setValue:dateString forHTTPHeaderField:@"If-Modified-Since"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
    [connection release];   
}
```

If I remove the first line of this method (where I'm adding "" to the url), the variable is retained. If I remove it, it gets released. This makes no sense to me at all.

I've tried declaring `sponsorUrl` with `@propterty (nonatomic, retain)`; I've tried declaring `sponsorUrl` statically; I've tried adding `[sponsorUrl retain]` where I set it, but it doesn't make a difference. The only thing that works is "touching" the variable before making the second request.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have u tried [alloc init]; on the sponsorURL. I've got a similar problem and this solved it... just try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your are using a convenience constructor the variable is autoreleased! Only if you are using methods like alloc, copy or new they are retained implicitly.

Secondly, by writing sponsorUrl = .... your are not using the generated setter but the generated instance variable. You will need to write self.sponsorUrl = @"Blah"; or [self setSponsorUrl:@"blah"] in order to have the setter retain the variable.

Comment: You and @sergio are correct. I knew that @"" was sugar, but I didn't recognize the implications. So if you initialize the string with `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""]`, what is the best way to reset the string? Do you just do `[sponsorUrl initWithString:@""]` again

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"? As a normal string is normally immutable the value of the string will be the same for his whole lifetime. If you want to clear the value, just pass is a new instance of an empty string, like self.sponsorUrl = [NSString initWithString:@""]; or even better, just set it to nil.

Comment: Sorry. That was a stupid question. I'm just not used to thinking on such a low level. If you had this: `NSString *mystring = @"one"; mystring = @"two";`... Here, `@"one"` will be released. And because of the sugar `@""`, `@"two"` will at a later point be autoreleased. ...right?

Comment: No, strings created like NSString *myString = @"blah" will never be released. In your comment you are creating thee instances of NSConstantString. Look my question I've asked about one year ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804943/difference-bewteen-declaring-a-nsstring-with-alloc-and-init-and-assigning-with

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it seems you have some issues with memory management.

It is pretty difficult to explain what is happening because you are not providing the full code that uses your variables. Just as an example, take the statement:

```
sponsorUrl = [sponsorUrl stringByAppendingString:@""];
```

what you do is assigning to `sponsorURL` a new value; the old value (the one you initialized the variable with in the first place, i.e., the one that got the `retain` you mention) is released (`stringByAppendingString` forges a new object); the new object that `sponsorURL` points to is an autoreleased object whose lifetime is not exactly known: we only know that at some point it will be freed (possibly at the next main loop iteration). So, by "touching" the variable, you are assigning a new value to it which has a lifetime starting with the point where you touch the variable... pretty unreliable, in any case.

My suggestion is the following:

1. define two properties in your class to handle `sponsorURL` and `sponsorImage`;
2. make them of the `retain` kind;
3. assign value to them only through their accessor methods, i.e, self.sponsorURL = [...]
4. make sure that any objects you assign to the properties are `autoreleased` objects (or else, do a release with the assignment).

If you provide more code, then it would be possible to review it more thoroughly, but if you follow the guidelines above, you will have no problems at all (approx...)

Comment: You and @yan.kun correctly identified the issue. I'm sorry I didn't include more of my code. There isn't a lot of it, but I thought that including the whole thing would obscure the problem. Two questions: In my code, `sponsorUrl` was actually static; does making something static change how it is retained? And to concatenate a string that I want to retain, should I do `[[someString stringByAppendingString:@"..."] retain]`.

Comment: `static` at the file (global) level will make the variable accessible exclusively from within that file; it is just a lexical thing, no relation with lifetime or retain cycle. About the second question, you are right: `stringByAppendingString` will give you an autorelease object; you need to call `retain` on it if you want to keep it alive (under your control) or assign it through the property setter (self.sponsorURL =...) which will do the retain for you.